# Performance of PIVOT and MERGE - is there a better way I can do this?

Tags: sql-server, merge, pivot

Sorry, this might be a bit out of scope for the community here, but I wanted to get a second opinion.

I have  a table with the following structure

```
Table_1 
TYPE    ITEM    DATE        QTYA    QTYB    QTYC
X       AAA     17/08/2015  100     200     300 
X       AAA     18/08/2015  100     170     240 
Y       BBB     17/08/2015  100     240     100
```

I need to use this table as a source for a merge, but the target table is formatted completely differently

```
Table_2 
ITEM   QTYA_1   QTYA_2......QTYA_31 QTYB_1  QTYB_2  QTYB_3......QTYB_31 QTYC_1  QTYC_2....QTYC_31
```

(the numbers suffixed at basically the day of the month)

I can convert Table 1 to the format of Table 2 using a mix of UNION ALL and PIVOT, but the performance isn't that good  - particularly since I have to save the information in a temp table first before merging it in (Each 'type' in Table_1 has a different start date and I cannot overwrite previous values in Table_2 starting from a different date - basically I have to merge the table 3 or 4 times with a different item type and different start date)

Here's what I got so far

```
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO #TEMP_PIVOT_TABLE
INSERT INTO #TEMP_PIVOT_TABLE SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT ITEM, 'QTYA_' + CONVERT(DATETIMEFROMPARTS(day,DATE) AS VARCHAR) as 'Quantity Type', QTY_A FROM TABLE_1
        UNION_ALL
    SELECT ITEM, 'QTYB_' + CONVERT(DATETIMEFROMPARTS(day,DATE) AS VARCHAR) as 'Quantity Type', QTY_B FROM TABLE_1
        UNION_ALL
    SELECT ITEM, 'QTYC_' + CONVERT(DATETIMEFROMPARTS(day,DATE) AS VARCHAR) as 'Quantity Type', QTY_C FROM TABLE_1
    ) A
    PIVOT
    (SUM(QUANTITY) FOR QUANTITY_TYPE IN ([QTYA_1], [QTYA_2],.....[QTYA_31],[QTYB_1].....[QTYC_31],[QTYC_1].....[QTYC_31])) AS B

----For each different date per item_type, construct a string only selecting those days in the month.
Then merge the results from #TEMP_PIVOT_TABLE into TABLE_2 for each Item TYPE` with dynamic SQL
```

1) Is there any better way to do the PIVOT command? The performance of the UNION ALL commands isn't encouraging - particularly since  the table I'm reading from has large amounts of data. I'm also simplifying here for the sake of brevity - the actual table needs to map 5 columns or so, each with 31 days

2) Is there a better way to do the MERGE? I dislike using a loop + Dynamic SQL to basically read the same dataset repeatedly just so to merge on different columns, but I can't see a different way. That and building the MERGE command dynamically with so many columns will make it troublesome for future maintenance.

Does anyone have an idea how I can go about this more efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the `union all` internal query with the following query. This query needs only one table hit instead of hitting table for each column.

To unpivot the data use `cross apply` with `table valued constructor`

```
select ITEM,[Quantity Type],QTY 
from yourtable 
cross apply 
(
values 
('QTYA_' + CONVERT(DATEPART(day,DATE) AS VARCHAR),QTY_A),
('QTYB_' + CONVERT(DATEPART(day,DATE) AS VARCHAR),QTY_B),
('QTYC_' + CONVERT(DATEPART(day,DATE) AS VARCHAR),QTY_C),
) 
CS ([Quantity Type],QTY)
```

Comment: Never used [CROSS APPLY] before, will look into it now, thanks! Any suggestions for the MERGE conundrum?